# An association rules algorithm that maintains the order of items

Tags: data-mining, association-rules

For example: if my dataset contains (A, B), but does not contain (B, A). Then the algorithm may generate the rule A -> B, but will not generate the rule B -> A.

Is there an association rules algorithm, or variation of an algorithm, that respects the order of items in this manner?

Comment: There's the SPADE algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be looking for a sequential pattern mining algorithm, such as apriori all.

> Agrawal, Rakesh, and Ramakrishnan Srikant. "Mining sequential
> patterns." Data Engineering, 1995. Proceedings of the Eleventh
> International Conference on. IEEE, 1995.

Implementation of many current algorithms for mining sequential patterns is available in [SPMF](http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/index.php?link=algorithms.php).